# How do I know if compilation was sucessful or it failed with process.start() and devenv.exe?

Tags: c#, compilation, process.start, devenv

I have the following code which builds a project using Process.Start() and devenv.exe:

```
RegistryKey rkey = Registry.LocalMachine;

//找到devenv.exe路径
RegistryKey rkey1 = rkey.OpenSubKey(REGISTKEY, false);
string devenvPath = rkey1.GetValue("").ToString();

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(devenvPath);
startInfo.Arguments = "/rebuild \"debug|x86\" " + solutionPath;

//执行编译过程
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;

try
{
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

How can I detect whether the compilation was successful or not?

Comment: If you just want to automatically compile, it's better/easier to use directly msbuild rather than Visual Studio

Comment: I think you don't get my idea.No matter devenv.exe or msbuild,how can I konw compile fail?Show me your code.

Comment: Once you have the right tools, it's a matter of knowing how to use a search engine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072998/how-to-detect-the-status-of-msbuild-from-command-line-or-c-sharp

Comment: As your opinion,you can kill stackoverflow.It has no mean,Seach engine can solve everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevEnv.exe sets an `exitcode` when the build fails. Simply read out this exitcode and check if it is non-zero. There are a lot of questions on StackOverflow on that particular topic, but essentially what you need to do is

```
process.WaitForExit();
bool isCompilationSuccesful = (process.ExitCode == 0);
```

Comment: Lucky to meet you in stackoverflow.It worked,Thanks Again~